# Remove the background color

Tags: graphics, export

How do I remove the background color from the drawn graphic? 
When I insert the Mathematica-derived plot image (.emf) into the Word, I always find a white background color. How do you make these background colors transparent?

Comment: I tried "Background→None" but it failed.

Comment: Did you put `Background -> None` in the `Graphic` itself, or in the export statement? I'm on macOS, so I can't use the .emf format, but I do get a transparent background with a PNG if I add the `Background -> None` to the actual export statement. Adding it to the graphic itself resulted in a white background.

Comment: How are you exporting the graphic?

Comment: @MassDefect I just tried it, *.png *can, but *.emf* still has a white background

Comment: So if png works as expected, why not simply use this format. As far as I know, emf is a buggy format (at least it is not on the same level of maturity as other vector formats, e.g. pdf, eps,svg).

Comment: @yarchik When I use WORD printer to generate pdf files, the svg format will be blurred, and the emf format will not be blurred. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Yet another reason to use png! It is true that MS supports many formats, even pdf on mac os x. However, this support is not uniform across systems. It is true that png is not a vector format. You cannot modify the graph after you plotted it. But that is even better---no one will mess around with your files. I use pdf in combination with latex almost exclusively. However, if someone asks me to write a report in MS Word, I just use a little script to convert pdf->png. Works as a charm!

Comment: Which *Mathematica* version do you use? With version 12.0 I get EMF with transparent background from `p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}];
Export["bgissue.emf", p, Background -> None]`. You could also try exporting to EPS vector format.

Comment: @yarchik - "..., if someone asks me to write a report in MS Word" - Then, please enlighten them, patiently, about the many other options they have.

Comment: @niloderoock Enlighten...? I typically comply with the requirements. So far, no one complained about PNG. By the way, I like the crispness and the lucidity of vector graphics and use AI almost daily. But there is nothing wrong with pixel formats (even the lossy ones).

Comment: Sorry, I meant MS Word. But I do understand that in many orgs it is a standard.

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as that for PNG files:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}];
Export["~/tmp/bgissue.png", p, Background -> None]
```

[image: img]

It works the same way for PDF. When I import the exported PDF graphics into Inkscape and put a colored background behind the object, one can clearly see this

[image: img]

If it indeed doesn't work for EMF (which I cannot try on Linux), one choice might be to use PDF.

Comment: I will give it a try, thank you

Comment: However, the pdf file does not seem to be inserted into the word, and the png file is not in vector format and will be distorted when zoomed in.

Comment: @King.Max Long live Microsoft Word. Can't you convert the PDF into an EMF somehow?